# I/flutter (16745): LateInitializationError: Field 'email' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter

```
class _RigestritState extends State<Rigestrit> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late String email;
  late String password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backrond,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Text('تسجيل' ,style: logo, textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
              SizedBox(height: 50,),
              ButtenHint(hint: 'الايميل  ', onpressed:(value){ email = value;}, obscureText: false, ),
              ButtenHint(hint: 'كلمة السر ', onpressed:(value){password = value;}, obscureText: true, ),



              Mybouttn(color: blueColor, titel: 'تسجيل', onpressed: () async  {//to send the data to firebase
                try{
                  final newUer = await  _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, home.homePage);
                }catch(e){
                  print(e);

                }

              }),
```

Comment: You try to access `email` and `password` without setting these values, and `late` means that they will be initalized before accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name and Email are initialized as late but not initialized before accessing the field.

Fields are initialized with the value

```
String email = '';
String password = '';
```

or it should be initialized before accessing the value

```
  late String email;
  late String password;
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    email = '';
    password = '';
    super.initState();
  }
```

And the late keyword is mostly used to define the final value when the value might be available in the future.